# Remove city from world clock widget?

Tags: macos, big-sur, widgets

How can I remove a city from the word clock widget shown below?

[image: Bluetooth automatically connects then disconnects after a few seconds.]

Answer (score 12):

It looks like we are not able to add or delete a clock at this time.
Check [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252035655?answerId=253870894022#253870894022) from Apple Discussions :

> FWIW, you cannot add or delete cities, only change which of four cities you wish to display.

The closest solution is to add a single city clock widget...

Comment: A wonderful decision by Apple :) And someone came up with this idea.. amazing :)

Answer (score 8):

You can choose whatever cities you like as long as there are four of them :-)

Just click on city name you want to replace, choose new one using Search field or use drop-down list in pop-up window. Your new choice will be displayed instead of Apple default.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: well yes.. it's a paraphrasing of "you can't"